# Using a keyfile with TrueCrypt

Tags: windows-xp, truecrypt

A TrueCrypt Keyfile generator generates a keyfile of size 64 bytes. Can I change the size to become like 100 bytes by adding some more random data to it? Also, Is it good idea to store it on Online HDD on some server for backup?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend saving it just on a server for backup. If something happens to the key while you don't have access to the server then you have no way to decrypt your files. Personally I save the key on a USB thumb drive so it is always readily available.

Comment: Ideally you go and lock it in a safe and leave information in will with combination/key..., well you get the picture.

Comment: @ewanm89: Do you mean a physical safe to lock USB drive?

Comment: Well, I would choose CD, but yeah, somewhere safe to hide a backup.

Comment: How safe you need to be depends on your own purposes.

Comment: Is it not safe to put it in your mail account for example?

Comment: Anything on the Internet should be considered insecure, including your email. However, you are the judge of your security, and if you think someone compromising your email account is less of an issue than getting the data, then you'll be fine. If you use two-factor authentication in your email, you should be fine, too.